# Getting "Error: panTo: latLng must be of type LatLng" when trying to pan from a pop up map(v3) to parent map(v3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My **panTo** normally works fine. But now i want to pan the parent map from the popup map. So i am trying to do something like

```
window.opener.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
```

But it gives me error

```
Error: panTo: latLng must be of type LatLng
[Break On This Error]   

(110 out of range 45)
```

Actually when i had Google Maps v2 then i used `window.opener.moveMapToPoint();` then it worked. But now it is not working. Please advice me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.opener.map.panTo(new window.opener.google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
```

Passing javascript objects across windows can be tricky.